# Efficient Method for Distance Comparison in Euclidean Space

Tags: algorithms, euclidean-distance

I have a vector of 2D Euclidean coordinates, and I need to find out if two or more points are within a distance threshold.

The naive approach is to compare each point with every other point, but I am not interested in **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** solutions. There are no other information or data that can be used to restrict the search space.

What is a good algorithm that has a runtime complexity of **O(nlog(n))** or faster? I am working with C++, and I am looking into Boost's r-tree (not sure it is appropriate).

Comment: (You can interleave (fixed point?) coordinate bits: In, say, ascending order of coordinates, points  close in position are close in Euclidean space.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search

Comment: We don't normally use software suggestions here, but for nearest-neighbour search in C++, I can recommend nanoflann.

Comment: Do you need _one_ or all pairs within the threshold, or the closest two points?

Comment: A very simple solution for “better than n^2”: For maximum distance < delta: Sort in ascending order by x-coordinate. Then compare every point a against all points b with a.x <= b.x < a.x + delta. Far from optimal, but much better than n^2 if delta is small.

Comment: @gnasher729: this multiplies then number of comparisons by delta/width (assuming an uniform distribution), which can be small, but the complexity remains O(N²).

Comment: "Two or more points": do you need to know all close pairs, or just check if there is one ? This makes a big difference.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I said "better than n^2". From n^2/2 to maybe n^2/100 comparisons is a massive improvement at minimal cost.

Comment: @gnasher729:  in the asymptotic sense, $n^2$ and $\dfrac{n^2}{100}$ are equal and are not $O(n\log(n))$, you know that.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something along these lines.  My solution: Pick one of the dimensions and divide it into 'buckets' of width equal to the threshold (only finitely many buckets are required for finitely many points).  Then place each point into its bucket; when doing so, check for proximity to another point against all points already in the same bucket plus the (at most) two immediately adjacent buckets.  Because of the chosen bucket width, no point in any other bucket can be too close.  If the points are reasonably scattered in two dimensions, there should need to be approximately O(N) comparisons, I estimate.  Of course, it is possible for some point sets to be badly distributed (e.g all in one bucket), so you may need to do some preliminary calculation on the point set to pick which dimension is better to divide.

Comment: Assuming M buckets and a uniform distribution (a favorable case), you will need M.(N/M)²=N²/M comparisons. The idea can be extended to that of a grid with M² buckets, leading to N²/M² comparisons.

Comment: @PMar if all points are in the same bucket: If you look for _one_ solution you get it quite quickly. If you look for _all_ solutions then the number of solutions is huge, and you can't be faster than O ("number of solutions") obviously, but if you count operations per solution you should be doing quite well.